# How to continue to run Tests in same browser in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Iam new to selenium webdriver,

In some scenario my tests case got failed,i want to run the tests from the same place (i.e. w/o closing the browser)from where the issue occured by commenting the previous code. how to do that in selenium webdriver. ( Like run from step in QTP )

Can anyone Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to reuse the browser, you can't initialize it in every test, so you need to use a singleton pattern in which you will have an unique webdriver.

So, instead of using the `@before` and `@after` clauses to initialize and close that browser, you want to use `@beforeclass` and `@afterclass`. Then, every test method in that class will use the same browser, from the exact point where the previous test left it.

But this will happen in the same test cycle. As far as I know, there is no possibility to use an instance of a browser launched in a different cycle, or manually opened.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way i am aware of, but that can should implicate in some problems if you decide to run the same test in parallel. I'd advise you study a little bit about `static` parameters to see if it suits you.

When you start your first test do it as follows:

```java
static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // Could be any Driver();
```

That way any test that you call `driver.someFunction();` will work, as long as you don't call for `close()` or `quit()` until you reach the last test.

Comment: Thanks @aimbire for replying,  what i understand,  suppose if iam having 3 tests in test suites, if first test got Passed after performing some operations on the browser, then 2nd test will continue to run from the current browser, i.e. without launching the new browser.  if we declare this [static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); ]

Comment: Between test suites i have never tried, so i can't guarantee you.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround found here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3927

```
WebDriver  driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:7055/hub" DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```